# Plot graph in MS Excel using multi axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a table with many of lines (alice, bob, etc.) per each date:

```
x           line    y
2015-04-10  alice   11032024
2015-04-10  bob     1492804
2015-04-10  clown   845033
2015-04-10  mary    6753325
```

I need to draw a plot graph like this:

[image]

How can I do it in MS Excel 2003? If not, may be another same app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do it with a pivot chart, I have only Excel 2010 installed, so I can't tell you step by step, but this is the idea:

- [insert a pivot chart](http://www.keystonelearning.com/resources/articles/excel_2003_creating_a_pivotchart)
- set: line -> legend fields, x -> axis fields, y -> values (if you don't have duplicated values (same name at the same date) then selecting either sum() either average() will give the same result)
- now it almost done, but you'll probably have gaps in the lines, to fix it you'll need to change how Excel manage missing data: link [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/884406) or [here](http://excel.tips.net/T003054_Controlling_the_Plotting_of_Empty_Cells.html).